# Formatting of multipart HTTP request body output with restsharp

Tags: c#, push-notification, httprequest, restsharp, azure-notificationhub

I am creating a restsharp request in order to trigger a batch direct send push request off to Azure notification hub.

I am receiving a 400 Bad Request response, with the message; Could not find 'notifications' part in the multipart content supplied.

The request looks like such;

```
const string multipartContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"simple-boundary\"";
const string authSignature = "myvalidauthsignature";
const string url = "mynotificanhuburl";
const string message = "Some message";

var restClient = new RestClient
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri(url),
    Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888),
};

var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(Method.POST)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
    AlwaysMultipartFormData = true
};

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", multipartContentType);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", authSignature);
request.AddHeader("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "gcm");

request.AddParameter("notification", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = new { message } }), ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("devices", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<string> { "123", "456" }), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

I can see the raw request via Fiddler;

```
POST https://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/xxx/messages/$batch?direct&api-version=2015-04 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: [redacted]
ServiceBusNotification-Format: gcm
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299
Host: [redacted]
Content-Length: 412
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notification"

{"data":{"message":"Some message"}}
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="devices"

["123","456"]
-------------------------------28947758029299--
```

Which looks about right. If I copy this into postman with the headers etc, I can see the same error response. **HOWEVER** in postman when I remove the quote marks around the parameter names, it works and returns a 201 Created response.

So this works....

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=notification
```

This doesn't

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notification"
```

Which seems really peculiar. As we are using restsharp however I don't think I have any direct control over the raw output for the request body. I am wondering;

- Is there a restsharp setting to manage these quote, perhaps a formatting setting
- Why would the Azure endpoint reject a parameter name with quotes

It is possible that the issue is elsewhere and this is a red herring, but this does seem to be responsible.

Appreciate any help...

Answer (score 1):

According our documentation, request should look like this:

```
POST https://{Namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{Notification Hub}/messages/$batch?direct&api-version=2015-08 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="simple-boundary"
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2f{Namespace}.servicebus.windows.net%2f{Notification Hub}%2fmessages%2f%24batch%3fdirect%26api-version%3d2015-08&sig={Signature}&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature
ServiceBusNotification-Format: gcm
Host: {Namespace}.servicebus.windows.net
Content-Length: 431
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive


--simple-boundary
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: inline; name=notification

{"data":{"message":"Hello via Direct Batch Send!!!"}}
--simple-boundary
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: inline; name=devices

["Device Token1","Device Token2","Device Token3"]
--simple-boundary--
```

So, the `name` parameter's value is not quoted (`name=devices`). I've not found any RFC which would explicitly specify requirements regarding the situation. However, in examples inside of RFCs a values appear quoted. And because of that I'm going to fix the service to support both options. Fix should come with next deployment in a week or so.

Comment: Amazing, thanks efimovandr! If the notification and device parameter names can accept quoted versions then it should work for us. Is there anywhere I can monitor the deployment/release status to know when this happens? I will mark as answer when it comes through OK.

Comment: Looks like the latest deployment has been completed worldwide. So, fix should be available.

Comment: Hi efimovandr, that did indeed resolve that specific issue so thanks for changing that! However, the next falldown for restsharp was being unable to specify the content type on a multi-part param. So unfortunately it was unable to create the required formatting.

I just used a normal HttpClient and got the formatting correct and it works great. However because the question was actually about formatting with RestSharp, I don't want to mark the answer as correct as it may mislead others. Thanks again for making the change though!

Answer (score 1):

I was plagued by this for a few days and was diligently searching for a solution with RestSharp and was unable to find one as it always default the content type to "multipart/form-data". I know the OP was looking for a way to do this with RestSharp but I don't believe there is currently.My solution comes from a few different posts over a few days so I apologize for not linking to them. Below is a sample Function to perform a multipart/related POST with json body and base64 pdf string as the file.

```
public static void PostBase64PdfHttpClient(string recordID, string docName, string pdfB64)
    {
        string url = $"baseURL";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var myBoundary = "------------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_";
        string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"UN:PW"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {auth}");

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{url}/api-endpoint");
        request.Headers.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        MultipartContent mpContent = new MultipartContent("related", myBoundary);
        mpContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", $"multipart/related; boundary={myBoundary}");

        dynamic jObj = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(); jObj.ID = recordID; jObj.Name = docName;
        var jsonSerializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj, jsonSerializeSettings);

        mpContent.Add(new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        mpContent.Add(new StringContent(pdfB64, Encoding.UTF8, "application/pdf"));

        request.Content = mpContent;

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    }
```